# What is the use of WPFFontCache Service in WPF? WPFFontCache_v0400.exe taking 100 % CPU all the time this exe is running, why?

Tags: wpf

What is acutally the functionality of WPFFontCache in WPF?. Sometime it is takeing too much CPU usage because of this system in hanging and my Application. Is there any problem disabling the service from the windows service. The big concern is why it is hanging my Application?.

Comment: Any use or functionality we could gain using WPFFontCache service falls apart by its 100% CPU [ab]use; At that rate who wants that optimization!??  I would prefer no font optimization and disable the service.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613584.aspx)

> The WPF Font Cache service shares font data between WPF applications. The first WPF application you run starts this service if the service is not already running. If you are using Windows Vista, you can set the "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Font Cache 3.0.0.0" service from "Manual" (the default) to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" to reduce the initial start-up time of WPF applications.

There's no harm in disabling it, but WPF apps tend to start faster and load fonts faster with it running.
It is supposed to be a performance optimization. The fact that it is not in your case makes me suspect that perhaps your font cache is corrupted. To clear it, follow these steps:

1. Stop the WPF Font Cache 4.0 service.
2. Delete all of the WPFFontCache_v0400* files. In Windows XP, you'll find them in your `C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Local Settings\Application Data\` folder.
3. Start the service again.

Comment: if i delete the folder and restart the service, application is working properly but the same problem presist as it goes on .

Comment: The directory is not visible. Even not when you enable "show hidden files and folders". Paste the path in the address bar or via Start->Run.

Comment: @Joop: It's visible on my machine, but yes, I have all hidden files/folder shown, including the system ones. You can also use the `del` command from the command line.

Answer (score 8):

Use This its is very useful for your solution:

1. Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
2. Scroll down to 'Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 4.0.0.0' and then right click and select properties
3. In the window then select 'disabled' in the startup type combo

Answer (score 1):

After installing Free BitDefender AntiVirus the services related to the AntiVirus used about 80 MB of my computer's Memory. I also noticed that after installing BitDefender the service related to windows Presentation Font Cache was also installed: "WPFFontCache_v0300.exe". I disabled the service from stating automatically and now BitDefender Free AntiVirus use only 15-20 MB (!!!) of my computer's Memory! As far as I concern, this service affected negatively the memory usage of my PC inother services. I recommend you to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut way: (windows xp)

1) click Start > run > services.msc

2) Scroll down to 'Windows Presentation Foundation Font Cache 4.0.0.0' 
and then right click and select properties

Answer (score 0):

for win xp

Steps

1. [windows key] + R, type services.msc, search for the running instance of "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Font Cache". For my case its 4.0. Stop the service.
2. [windows key] + R, type C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Local Settings\Application Data\, delete all font cache files.
3. Start the "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Font Cache" service.